# How can I write an empty case in Swift?

Tags: swift

Since swift does not fallthrough `case` statements in `switch`, How can I write an empty case statement without getting an error?

```
let a = 50
switch a {
case 0..10:
case 10..100:
    println("between 10 and 100")
default:
    println("100 and above")
}
```

How can I make the first case stop the switch?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
let a = 50
switch a {
case 0..10:
    break // Break the switch immediately
case 10..100:
    println("between 10 and 100")
default:
    println("100 and above")
}
```

Keyword `break` is optional, but not in this *case* :)

Comment: This is the correct answer. From [*The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID139): "Because Swift’s switch statement is exhaustive and does not allow empty cases, it is sometimes necessary to deliberately match and ignore a case in order to make your intentions explicit. You do this by writing the break statement as the entire body of the case you want to ignore."

Answer (score 49):

To prevent the error:

> Case label in a switch should have at least one executable statement

... use `()` in case label like in the following example. Also works with `default` label.

```
let a = 1
switch a {
case 1:
    ()
case 2:
    println("2")
default:
    ()
}
```

Comment: I ask for learning, what is happening after () statement run? I mean what is the equality of () statements for Swift language. It is a break or something like that?

Comment: It's an empty tuple. I'm guessing it doesn't produce a warning like other literals, which would also work, because the compiler probably has logic to handle empty function argument lists, for example.

Comment: Or just use `break`