# Noop for Swift's Exhaustive Switch Statements

Tags: swift

Swift requires exhaustive switch statements, and that each case have executable code.

> 'case' label in a 'switch' should have at least one executable statement

Has anybody settled on a good way to handle the cases where you don't want to actually do anything? I can put a println() in there, but that feels dirty.

Comment: [How can I write an empty case in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108060/how-can-i-write-an-empty-case-in-swift/30996976)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

According to [the book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Statements.html), you need to use `break` there:

> The scope of each case can’t be empty. As a result, you must include at least one statement following the colon (:) of each case label. Use a single `break` statement if you don’t intend to execute any code in the body of a matched case.

Comment: Oh, again Swift breaks the law of minimum surprise :)

Comment: @Sulthan after a little consideration, `break` makes sense. It provides a way to exit a case early, and also a way to specifically do *nothing*, even when your `default:` has non-nothing behavior

Comment: @Jiaaro The need for `break` indicates that the branches without `break` might fallthrough.

Comment: A simple `()` wokrs, too. Nevertheless I prefer `break` as it makes things more clear. Use the keyword `fallthroug` to fall through statements.

Comment: This is quite annoying when you want to briefly comment out the only line that's in the `default:` case. That doesn't seem like a good thing. I also agree that it is suggestive of c's fall through behaviour, which isn't what Swift does (nice to know it can fall through though).

Comment: And I had to come here just to make sure that the break wasn't going to quit an enclosing loop early..

Comment: Why on Earth does Swift need a `default` statement in a `switch`? i have a lot of useless `default: break` code all around my projects. It seems illogical to me.

Comment: @AndroidGuy `default` is required to make `switch` [exhaustive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26686542/335858).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes but why does it **have** to be exhaustive? If no `default` is given, simply exit the `switch` if all the other conditions aren't met. Why it isn't so?

Comment: @AndroidGuy This is done to let you catch programming errors at compile time in situations when your `switch` has no `default`, e.g. when you add a new element to `enum` and forget to modify a `switch` that handles it.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a `break` statement:

```
let vegetable = "red pepper"
var vegetableComment: String = "Nothing"
switch vegetable {
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    break // does nothing
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)?"
default:
    vegetableComment = "Everything tastes good in soup."
}
```

Example modified from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html)

Answer (score 9):

Do nothing in exhaustive switch case statements:

Swift:

```
switch yourVariable {
case .someCase:
    break
}
```

SwiftUI:

```
switch yourVariable {
case .someCase:
    EmptyView() // break does not work with ViewBuilder
}
```

Using EmptyView() instead of break in SwiftUI views prevents the error:

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function
> builder ViewBuilder.

EmptyView() is a SwiftUI standard view (tested with Xcode 12, iOS 14) and does not need to be defined yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Below is one option for null statement, but maybe not a good solution. I cannot find a statement like python pass

```
{}()
```

for switch case, break is better choice.

```
break
```

Comment: Excellent! This is what I searched for. It allows me to define `let noop: Void = {}()` and to use statements like `if condition { noop }` and to set a breakpoint at `noop`. I know this is ugly, but to set a conditional breakpoint slows down my app incredibly, say by a factor of 100, at least in Xcode 13.2.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `break` mentioned in other answers, I have also seen `()` used as a no-op statement:

```
switch 0 == 1 {
case true:
    break
case false:
    ()
}
```

Use `()` if you find `break` confusing or want to save 3 characters.

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution I use for my default case is:

```
default: ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check specific case, no need to be `exhustive` with `switch` `case`s

Say you have a enum like this,

```
enum Selection {
        case one
        case two
        case three
    }
var myCase = Selection.one
```

you can check like this,

```swift
    if case .one = myCase {
        print("one")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The cleanest solution I've found is to simply include your last statement in the switch case as your default.  This avoids the need to add `break` or other unnecessary statements while still covering all possible cases.

For example:

```swift
switch myVar {

case 0:
    myOtherVar = "Red"

case 1:
    myOtherVar = "Blue"

default:
    myOtherVar = "Green"

}
```

Comment: Hi @scottyhardy. This is really not the point of the question. You wrote the answer to the question: "How to avoid having to add an empty default case" (or something along those lines). In your case you are actually doing something in all of the cases. But let's say you have a case (like the number 2 for example) where you don't want to do anything, then in that case you come back to the same question: what to do when in a switch case we don't want to do anything? Long story short: use break.