# How do I create a noop block for a switch case in Swift?

Tags: swift

How do I create a noop block for a switch case in Swift? Swift forces you to have at least one executable statement under your case, including default.  I tried putting an empty { } but Swift won't take that.  Which means that Swift's switch case is not totally translatable between if-else and vice versa because in if-else you are allowed to have empty code inside the condition.

e.g.

```
switch meat {

   case "pork":
     print("pork is good")

   case "poulet":
     print("poulet is not bad")

   default:
     // I want to do nothing here
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Noop for Swift's Exhaustive Switch Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141900/noop-for-swifts-exhaustive-switch-statements)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
default:
  break
```

Apple talks about this keyword in [**this article**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-XID_976). See [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_174), too.

> Although break is not required in Swift, you can still use a break statement to match and ignore a particular case, or to break out of a matched case before that case has completed its execution.

Comment: It's also possible to write:
`default: ()`

Comment: @neave, is there any official documentation explains why `default: ()` works?

Comment: @mrfour `()` is an empty tuple, so the statement is simply evaluated and does nothing. `default: break` is probably more understandable, though.