# Not sure how to avoid junk in default statement of Swift switch

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

Switch statements must be exhaustive in Swift, so I have to put something in my default statement to keep the compiler happy.

```
private enum TextFieldType: Int {
    case street1 = 0
    case street2
    case street3
    case town
    case postcode
    case phone
    case email
}

@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(textField: UITextField, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    switch textField.tag {
    case TextFieldType.street1.rawValue:
        self.model?.address1 = textField.text
    case TextFieldType.street2.rawValue:
        self.model?.address2 = textField.text
    case TextFieldType.street3.rawValue:
        self.model?.address3 = textField.text
    case TextFieldType.town.rawValue:
        self.model?.town = textField.text
    case TextFieldType.postcode.rawValue:
        self.model?.postcode = textField.text
    case TextFieldType.phone.rawValue:
        self.model?.primaryPhone = textField.text
    case TextFieldType.email.rawValue:
        self.model?.email = textField.text
    default:
        println("")
    }
}
```

In this situation (above), how would you handle the default statement? Putting println("") for the sake of it isn't right.

Comment: I have closed this question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224441/how-do-i-create-a-noop-block-for-a-switch-case-in-swift because it looked like the same question (with a good answer) to me. There is a "reopen" vote now, so somebody seems to disagree. Perhaps that person could leave a comment why (s)he thinks that this is a different question. I have no problems to retract my close-as-a-duplicate-vote if I was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `break` to leave the switch-statement:

```
default:
    break
```

Comment: lol of course. damn it