# Exhaustive condition of switch case in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

The Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) says

> Every switch statement must be exhaustive. That is, every possible
>   value of the type being considered must be matched by one of the
>   switch cases.

So in new Xcode I have placed a code like this

```
println(UInt16.min); // Output : '0'
println(UInt16.max); // Output : '65535'

var quantity : UInt16 = 10;

switch quantity {
case 0...65535: //OR case UInt16.min...UInt16.max:
    println();
default:
    println();
}
```

Now if i remove the default section I get a compiler error:

> Switch must be exhaustive
>   Do you want to add missing cases? Fix

So my question is for a case that I have mentioned as `case 0...65535:` have I not mentioned all the case values for an `UInt16` ?? But still I am getting an error ?? Why am I getting this error, Did i miss something ??

Comment: This code compiles with Xcode 7.3/Swift 2.2, so the compiler has become smarter :)

Comment: ... but it crashes at runtime :(

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Swift only truly verifies that a `switch` block is exhaustive when working with `enum` types. Even a switching on `Bool` requires a `default` block in addition to `true` and `false`:

```
var b = true
switch b {
case true:  println("true")
case false: println("false")
}
// error: switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause
```

With an `enum`, however, the compiler is happy to only look at the two cases:

```
enum MyBool {
    case True
    case False
}

var b = MyBool.True
switch b {
case .True:  println("true")
case .False: println("false")
}
```

If you need to include a `default` block for the compiler's sake but don't have anything for it to do, the `break` keyword comes in handy:

```
var b = true
switch b {
case true:  println("true")
case false: println("false")
default: break
}
```

Comment: So you mean iOS says its exhaustive but it actually is not ?

Comment: @GirishNair I'm not sure I follow - basically, even though **we** can tell the switch block is exhaustive, the compiler isn't doing the work to determine that. So we need to provide `default:` even when that pattern will never be hit.

Comment: I just experienced this with a non-optional Bool and thought I was missing something.  I filed a bug report: 19582311

Comment: `switch` no longer requires `default` for `Bool` if you have cases for `true` and `false`.  I'm not sure when this change happened, but with Swift 2.2 in Xcode 7.3, the above works.

Comment: @NateCook . Just checked on xCode 10, default is not required for Bool if true and false are present.  "error: switch must be exhaustive" is not coming

Comment: Confirmed; this answer is no longer true in Swift. I would suspect since Swift 2 or 3.

Answer (score 11):

Part of why you see that error because the compiler can't verify that switch is exhaustive without running code. The expression `0...65535` creates a `ClosedInterval` struct, and when the switch statement executes it has to ask that struct if the value `quantity` is in the interval. There's room for that to change at run time, so the compiler can't check it at compile time. (See the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).)

More generally, the compiler can't detect an exhaustive switch for integer values — even if you add specific cases for every integer value (`case 0: ... case 1: ... ... case 65535:`), it doesn't know your switch is exhaustive. (Theoretically it could, though: consider [filing a feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com) about this if it's something you'd like to see.)

As it stands, there are two scenarios where Swift can detect completeness and allow you to omit the `default` clause: enums and value binding in tuples. @NateCook's answer covers enums — if you switch on an enum value and have a `case` in your `switch` for every `case` in the enum, you don't need a `default`. You also don't need a `default` label if you switch on a tuple and bind every possible combination of values, as seen [in the Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_205):

```
switch anotherPoint {
case (let x, 0):
    println("on the x-axis with an x value of \(x)")
case (0, let y):
    println("on the y-axis with a y value of \(y)")
case let (x, y):
    println("somewhere else at (\(x), \(y))")
}
```

You might generalize this rule as "if the type system knows about the possible values of your type, it can detect `switch` completeness", but the fact that there's a level on which the type system doesn't know the range of possible (e.g.) `UInt32` values is sort of splitting hairs...

Comment: Nope...tried it with `UInt8` and it prompts you to add a default case even with all 256 numbers.

Comment: Ehh, that's what I get for posting from my phone and going off what I half remember. :) Edited answer with corrections and some further info.

Comment: "the compiler can't verify that switch is exhaustive without running code" - that is simply not true.

Comment: A third case now works without `default`.  A `switch` on a `Bool` doesn't require a default case if both `true` and `false` are covered.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.1. Either you need to specify all cases or Just include default block inside switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

(As of Swift 4.2, and probably earlier): I have a helper function that converts a `Bool?` into the `selectedSegmentIndex` for a UISegmentedControl with 2 segments. If the value is `nil` then neither segment should be selected. My function uses a switch, which returns the appropriate segment index for true or false values, and uses this to explicitly test for the `nil` and satisfy the compiler's need for it to be exhaustive:

```
case nil:  // only remaining possible value
    fallthrough
default:
    return UISegmentedControl.noSegment
```

Technically, the `case nil:` `fallthrough` isn't required because the `default:` will suffice, but this syntax may be useful if you want to explicitly test a value to make the code more self-documenting, or perhaps in another situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your enum was initialised as an optional which could be either case or nil