# Switch statement must be exhaustive

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following `switch` statement and it seems to be perfectly exhaustive.

```
switch (point.x > frame.origin.x, point.y > frame.origin.y) {
case (true, true): // Bottom right
    moveSubviewX = subview.frame.origin.x - moveBy
    moveSubviewY = subview.frame.origin.y - moveBy
case (false, true): // Bottom left
    moveSubviewX = subview.frame.origin.x + moveBy
    moveSubviewY = subview.frame.origin.y - moveBy
case (true, false): // Top right
    moveSubviewX = subview.frame.origin.x - moveBy
    moveSubviewY = subview.frame.origin.y + moveBy
case (false, false): // Top left
    moveSubviewX = subview.frame.origin.x + moveBy
    moveSubviewY = subview.frame.origin.y + moveBy
}
```

With a `tuple` that has two `Bool` components there are only 4 possible variations. Why do I still have a suggestion to include "a default clause"?

Comment: Is `point` a CGPoint? Is `frame` a CGRect?

Comment: Correct, but `frame.origin` is a `CGPoint` too, so I don't see a possible conflict.

Comment: I was asking to ensure that no possible types were involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exhaustive condition of switch case in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686542/exhaustive-condition-of-switch-case-in-swift)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xcode checks if the switch statement is exhaustive only if you're switching enums. For every other case, it checks if there is a default statement, and if not, it puts up a warning.

You can either use enums, or squelch the warning if you want to, or, just add the missing default statement doing nothing.

Comment: Do you have any reference links to substantiate your answer?

Comment: I don't think I remember seeing it anywhere officially, but you can check this site if you're wondering which is the warning exactly you're looking for: http://www.futureworkshops.com/articles/xcode-warnings.html

Comment: No problem. I think it's a much bigger hassle to check whether switch statements are truly exhaustive for situations that don't have a clearly defined number of cases, rather than implement a few simpler checks.