# Can a swift switch be exhaustive for type Double without a default case?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Can a swift switch be exhaustive for type Double without a default case?

This switch (without a default case) gives the error: switch must be exhaustive:

```
    var minY = 1.0

    switch minY {
    case -(Double.infinity)..<0.9:
        yAxisMinimum = 0.0
    case (0.9..<0.99):
        yAxisMinimum = 0.9
    case (0.99..<0.999):
        yAxisMinimum = 0.99
    case (0.999..<0.9999):
        yAxisMinimum = 0.999
    case (0.9999...Double.infinity):
        yAxisMinimum = 0.9999
    }
```

But this switch, with the (useless) default case, works:

```
    var minY = 1.0

    switch minY {
    case -(Double.infinity)..<0.9:
        yAxisMinimum = 0.0
    case (0.9..<0.99):
        yAxisMinimum = 0.9
    case (0.99..<0.999):
        yAxisMinimum = 0.99
    case (0.999..<0.9999):
        yAxisMinimum = 0.999
    case (0.9999...Double.infinity):
        yAxisMinimum = 0.9999
    default:
        yAxisMinimum = 0.0
    }
```

I try to avoid default cases with my switches, but don't know if that's possible with a Double.

Comment: Well your first `switch`  hasn't covered all cases. You still need to deal with `NaN`s as well. (Though I have no idea whether that would fix the compiler error.)

Comment: You also haven't dealt with inf, either. In any case, I don't think the compiler has a check to determine exhaustivity for ints/doubles

Comment: Unrelated : `-(Double.infinity)..<0.9` could be written `..<0.9`

Comment: Well, you can do it without `default` by using `case _:` which will match anything, but I know that isn't what you want either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exhaustive condition of switch case in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686542/exhaustive-condition-of-switch-case-in-swift)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No [because only enum types can be exhaustively checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686542/exhaustive-condition-of-switch-case-in-swift).

But in this case, the problem is even deeper. Even if Integers could be exhaustively checked, you *still* couldn't exhaustively check Double without a `where` clause. One of the options is `.nan` ("not a number"), which you're not considering. So you might think to just add that case:

```
case .nan:
    yAxisMinimum = .nan
```

Not only won't this make it exhaustive, it won't even work the way you'd expect.

```
var minY = Double.nan

switch minY {
case -(Double.infinity)..<0.9:
    yAxisMinimum = 0.0
// ...
case .nan:
    yAxisMinimum = .nan
default:
    yAxisMinimum = 0
}

yAxisMinimum // 0
```

Why? Because of this:

```
var minY = Double.nan
minY == .nan   // false
```

NaN is unequal to *everything*, including NaN. So there's no way to include it directly in a switch statement. You have to use a `where` clause:

```
case _ where minY.isNaN:
    yAxisMinimum = .nan
```

And that's *definitely* beyond the compiler's ability to validate.

Comment: Rob - Your answer brings up a good point, but there are definitely things in Swift other than eNums, that don't require a default.  Here is an example straight from the Reference Manual (5.1): let anotherPoint = (2, 0)
switch anotherPoint {
case (let x, 0):
    print("on the x-axis with an x value of \(x)")
case (0, let y):
    print("on the y-axis with a y value of \(y)")
case let (x, y):
    print("somewhere else at (\(x), \(y))")
}
// Prints "on the x-axis with an x value of 2"