# The "switch" and "extension" rows get error when I run this code. Why?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 2000


    @IBAction func changeMapType(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            mapView.mapType = .standard
        } else {
            mapView.mapType = .satellite
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        func checkLocationAuthorization() {
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                mapView.showsUserLocation = true
                centerViewOnUserLocation()

            }
        }


        func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
            if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
                mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            }

        }

    extension MapScreen: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        func locationManager( manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        }

        func locationManager( manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        }
    }
    }
```

It says

> "Switch must be exhaustive"

on the func `checkLocationAuthorization` and it says

> "Declaration is only valid at file scope"

on the extension? How do i fix this?

Comment: Try to google "Switch must be exhaustive", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686542/exhaustive-condition-of-switch-case-in-swift

Comment: Your extension inside the MapViewController. It should be outside of controller scope.

Comment: Whats the controller scope?

Comment: Outside of the class you are trying to use it in.

Comment: You have messed up your braces. The closing brace for `viewDidLoad` is missing and it is down the bottom under the extension. All of your code is inside the viewDidLoad function. Extensions must me created outside the braces of the class, usually at the bottom of the file. the rest of your functions also need to not be created inside the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

In checkLocationAuthorization, handle all cases for authorizationStatus or add a default case like below

```
    func checkLocationAuthorization() {

       switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
       case .authorizedWhenInUse:
          mapView.showsUserLocation = true
          centerViewOnUserLocation()

       default:
         break
       }
    }
```

**Extension**

extension should be outside the controller scope.

```
class A {

}

extension A: <some protocol> {

}

// MARK: Doing a spefic work!! 
extension A { 

}
```

[swift extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)