# Why switch does not accept case nil in optional?

Tags: swift

I was working with optional in switch which I noticed switch cannot accept nil as a case!

```
func test(value: Bool?) {
    switch value {
    case true: print("true")
    case false: print("false")
    case nil: print("nil")
    }
}
```

> Error: Switch must be exhaustive

then I used default for solving the issue, but I am looking to learn why nil cannot work in first code?

Comment: This may help: [Exhaustive condition of switch case in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686542/exhaustive-condition-of-switch-case-in-swift)

Comment: use default instead

Comment: @Unmitigated Luckily, the Swift compiler is taught how to exhaustively match against the values of `Bool`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is just an incorrect diagnostic. You can add a `default` case, and this code will work, but I'm actually surprised that works.

You see, the value you're switching on is a `Bool?`, but 2 of the values you're comparing it against are `true` and `false`. The typical approach for this is to use pattern matching:

```
func test(value: Bool?) {
    switch value {
    case .some(true): print("true")
    case .some(false): print("false")
    case .none: print("nil")
    }
}
```

This works correctly, but it's a bit wordy. Luckily, Swift has a syntactic sugar for pattern matching against optionals, `?` and `nil`:

```
func test(value: Bool?) {
    switch value {
    case true?: print("true")
    case false?: print("false")
    case nil: print("nil")
    }
}
```

Both of these snippets compile and work fine. It does open a new question as to why your original cases worked, if only you added the `default`.

I suggest you post about this on Swift forums, to get more input from the compiler nerds :)

Answer (score 0):

An Optional is an enum with two cases, one which has the value associated: either .some(value) or .none

The correct way to use a switch for pattern matching an optional is:

```
switch optional {
case .some(let value): // do your stuff with value
case .none: // do your stuff when the optional is nil
}
```

Alternatively you could also use map on an optional to execute a closure when its value is not nil:

```
optional.map { value in 
    // do your stuff with the value 
}
```

With this approach the body closure passed to the map function only executes when the optional is not nil at runtime, otherwise it doesn’t executes.

Comment: The first code seems good, but the second one with map would capture all possible cases, so how the second one would benefit me?

Comment: It might in case you dom’t want to branch your code with a guard let or if let construct to unwrap an optional value.