# Non-exhaustive pattern match for Swift enum

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching

I have an enum I want to execute code only for certain cases and do nothing all other times (non-exhaustive)

This seems overly verbose for Swift

```
if num == .One || num == .Two || num == .Three || num == .Four {
    //code
}
```

This leaves me with a default case where I want to do nothing but still have to add something like a `print`

```
switch num {
case .One, .Two. Three, .Four:
    //code
default:
    print("do nothing but I still need to put something here")
}
```

I would like to do something like this... does it exist in Swift?

```
if case .One, .Two, .Three, .Four == num {
    //code            
}
```

Comment: Create an array and use its contains method. That's the functional way.

Comment: You can just use `break` instead of `print`. I tend to find that cleaner to use, plus you don't have the performance hit of using `print`.

Comment: You can also do `switch`, but then have `default` clause that is simply `default: ()` or `default: break`.

Comment: [Noop for Swift's exhaustive switch statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24141900)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if [.One, .Two, .Three, .Four].contains(num) {
```

Comment: I saw [an interesting wrapper for this](https://github.com/qutheory/vapor/blob/467355981c57ea7545b898af76a400565689d8e4/Sources/Vapor/Utilities/Equatable.swift) yesterday: `extension Equatable { func equals(any: Self...) -> Bool { return any.contains(self) }}` Allows you to write `num.equals(any: .One, .Two, .Three, .Four)` with an `Equatable`. (In Swift 3; you'd have to add an explicit first label name in v2.)

Answer (score 5):

You can always add a default case with no action:

```
switch value {
case .One:
    Some code here

default:
    break
}
```

break can always be used to signify that a case has no action, as well as explicitly terminate the action